# A trip to UK, from EU, on the 29 Jun to 3 of July 2019

Tags: visas, uk, eu-citizens, brexit

I'm thinking of travelling to the UK, from a EU country, on the 29 Jun to 3 of July 2019.

Shall I need a Visa, or is my National Identity Card enough?

Comment: Last I heard, people who all ought to _know_ were disagreeing among themselves whether airlines can even continue flying in case the UK crashes out on April 12. By the end of June basic communications would probably be sorted out even in pessimistic scenarios, but preserving the ability to use identity cards for travel will likely be quite far down anyone's list of priorities if all hell breaks lose with a no-deal Brexit. Better plan for having -- and bringing! -- an actual passport.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear, but even if you are allowed **visa-free** travel you might need a document that can be stamped on entry, i.e. a passport.